# scaffold.dart: Illegal character '8594'

Tags: dart, flutter, scaffold, illegal-characters

anyone knows how to solve this error?
I did not change anything in the scaffold file

the analyzer failed with the following error:

> Error in /Users/----/desktop/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/scaffold.dart: Illegal character '8594'.

Answer (score -1):

run

```
git clean -xfd
flutter doctor
```

in `~/desktop/flutter’